# Can't understand GDB backtrace output

Tags: multithreading, gdb, deadlock

I'm trying to debug a deadlock situation. I'm working on a `Linux (Debian)` machine and using `QT Creator`. I try debugging using the following `GDB` command:

`thread apply all bt`

The output of this command is:

```
158thread apply all bt
>&"thread apply all bt\n"
>~"\nThread 4 (LWP 6801):\n"
>~"#0  0x00007ffff6da6994 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#1  0x0008800002d0da5d in ?? ()\n"
>~"#2  0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#3  0x00007d640002dfe3 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#4  0x00007ffff3395ac0 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#5  0x00007ffff6d539dd in ?? ()\n"
>~"#6  0x00007d2000000400 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#7  0x0000000000000078 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#8  0x00007ffff6d8f9b6 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#9  0x0000000000000078 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#10 0x0000000000000010 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#11 0x00007ffff3395ac0 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#12 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#13 0x00007ffff6d539dd in ?? ()\n"
>~"#14 0x00007ffff6d9028c in ?? ()\n"
>~"#15 0x0000000000000004 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#16 0x00007d2000000400 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#17 0x00007ffff3394b10 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#18 0x00007fff00000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#19 0x00007d940000ca38 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#20 0x00007ffff3395ac0 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#21 0x0000000000000078 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#22 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"\nThread 3 (LWP 6800):\n"
>~"#0  0x00007ffff5c518bd in ?? ()\n"
>~"#1  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#2  0x00007ffff6d6e919 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#3  0x00000064f3b96040 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#4  0x00007ffff3b96a01 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#5  0x00007ffff3b96ac0 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#6  0x000000000048e149 in pTimerThread (pData=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffffff97328>) at /mnt/hgfs/Projects/deom/Modul/osTimer.c:267\n"
>~"Backtrace stopped: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffffff973c8\n"
>~"\nThread 2 (LWP 6799):\n"
>~"#0  0x00007ffff5c2a28d in ?? ()\n"
>~"#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()\n"
>~"\nThread 1 (LWP 6795):\n"
>~"#0  0x00007ffff67bd556 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#1  0x00007ffff3c03808 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#2  0x00007ffff7f64880 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#3  0x00007d140000ef80 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#4  0xfffffffeffffffff in ?? ()\n"
>~"#5  0x00007fffffffded0 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#6  0x00007ffff67bd604 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#7  0x00007ffff7f64880 in ?? ()\n"
>~"#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()\n"
>158^done
```

The only line that is human-readable for me is:

`>~"#6  0x000000000048e149 in pTimerThread (pData=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffffff97328>) at /mnt/hgfs/Projects/deom/Modul/osTimer.c:267\n"`

Shouldn't this command give the list of functions that have been recently called by each thread? Why does it just give list of addresses instead of directly functions' names? Is there a way to know which functions are defined in these addresses?

Answer (score 0):

The executable doesn't have debug symbols. Assuming you haven't stripped the symbols out, compile your object files with `-g` (assuming you're using gcc/clang).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding `QMAKE_CFLAGS += -g` to my `.pro` file as I'm working in `QT`. I made sure `-g` is called with `gcc` commands but this didn't solve the problem.